# obfuscate entry to textbox in FF

Tags: javascript

My two-stage login comprises a form, where username and pwd are entered, which links to a second form where a PIN code must be entered.

So; complete form 1, submit, complete form 2, submit and entry is permitted (subject to authentication).

Trouble is, the PINcode text box on form 2 is type='text', because I don't want the save password dialog to show on submission.  And, yet, I want to mask from prying eyes, whatever the user may enter.

The PIN must never be saved.

Most main browsers work without the JS. Firefox 72 does not.

I have looked at other 'solutions' but they were for antique versions of FF and I haven't been able to make them work in FF72.

for clarity to other's comments....
The JS ensures the PIN is masked out with discs but it's submitting it as type='password' which throws up the save password dialog, which I do not want to appear.

Here is my form

```js
 window.onload = function(){
            init(); 
        }
        function init(){
            var x = document.getElementById("PINcode");
            
            if( x ) {                 
                x.setAttribute("type","password");               
            }else{
                // do nothing
            }
        }
```

```css
 #PINcode {
        text-security:disc;
        -webkit-text-security:disc;
        -moz-text-security:disc;
    }
```

```html
    <form id='login-form-pin' class="form-signin" action="/$cp_location/pin-login.pl" method='post'>
    <div>
      <h1>WARNING:</h1>
      <p>$active_text</p>
      <label for="PINcode" class="sr-only">PIN Code</label>
      <input type="text" id="PINcode" name='PINcode' class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your PIN" required />
      <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name='Login' value="Enter your PIN" /> 
      <input type='hidden' name='action' value='personal pin entry' /> 
      <p>
        <a href="/$cp_location/resend_login_pin.pl?user=$entered_user_name&action=resend_pin">Send me a new PIN.</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/$cp_location/login.pl?logout=Logout">Force Log Out</a>
      </p>        
    </div>        
    </form>
```

That JS doesn't have any visual effect in FF.

Autocomplete='one-time-code' is no use here. It brings up the 'save password' dialog.

[edited with progress]
The form element is now as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="user_pin_code" name='user_pin_code' class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your PIN" onkeyup="obfuscateEntry();" autocomplete='off' required />
```

and I am using JS modified a little from that found in another thread

```
<script>
actualText = ""; 
  
function obfuscateEntry() {
  var x = document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value;
  var tempText = x.replace(/\\*/g,"");

  console.log( 'x =   ' + x );


      if(tempText == "")
      {
        actualText = actualText.substr(0, actualText.length - 1);
      }
      else {
        actualText += x.replace(/\\*/g,"");
      }
  
  document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value = "";
  
  for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
    document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value += "*";
    document.getElementById("PINcode").value = actualText;
  }
}
```

[/edit]

The only issue remaining is that the script can miss out some characters, if the PIN code is entered too quickly. I think that would require a separate question so I have posted the 'solution' for others.

Comment: Why not just use `type="password"` in you rmarkup?

Comment: @meagar - The OP said *"Also, I do not want the 'save password' dialog to appear. The PIN must never be saved."*

Comment: Your code works for me on macOS Catalina & FF v79+, as well as Windows 10 & FF v79+

Comment: It masks the entered PIN but when submitted it throws up the 'save password' dialog.  That seems to be because the JS converts the textbox to be type='password'. I want the masking offered by that but for it to be a textbox submission (to avoid the save pwd dialog).

Comment: `<input id="pin" type="password" autocomplete="one-time-code">`