# js loses chars if typed too quickly

Tags: javascript

OK, I got this completed and working and I've removed mention of some of the issues I had to assist with easy reading.

I am obfuscating the characters entered to a text box (id='user_pin_code') such that they appear to be ' * ' or ' **** ' according to the number of chars.
It's for the entry of a PIN code.

The first part takes the chars entered and replaces each with an ' * ' asterisk. So a 6 char PIN will show ' ****** '
All good so far, regardless of how quickly I type.

The next part takes the actual chars entered and populates another textbox (id='PINcode'), with the actual characters entered.
Trouble is, if I type quickly some are missed out.
so 'wxymdo' can be entered as 'wxmd'.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var actualTextEntered = ""; 


    $("#user_pin_code").keyup(function(e) {
                       
        var x = document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value;
                
        actualTextEntered += x.replace(/\\*/g,"");
                
        addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            const key = event.key; // const {key} = event; ES6+
            if ( key === "Backspace" ) {
                // Do something
                actualTextEntered = ''; 
                x='';
            }
        });
        
        
        
        document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value = "";
        
        for (var i=0;i<actualTextEntered.length;i++)
        {   
        document.getElementById("user_pin_code").value += "*";
        document.getElementById("PINcode").value = actualTextEntered;
        }   
        
        
    });

});
```

Comment: Why don't you use `<input type="password">`?

Comment: *“Should I be looking at this in a different way?”* Yes, you should try to stay as non-hacky as possible – it’s important for reliability and accessibility. Your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204659/obfuscate-entry-to-textbox-in-ff) says “I want to mask from prying eyes whatever the user may enter” – is that just a nice-to-have? Are these one-time codes? If yes to both, I would leave it as visible text; that’s pretty standard.

Comment: But why is it secret like a bank PIN? The “Send me a new PIN” link makes it sound like it’s ephemeral and maybe even a second factor.

Comment: Pretty sure what mess you up here is the `setTimeout` function, you should make each function call wait for the previous function call be done first, then call next function. What you do is not a good practice, but if you insist, implement a task queue for the timeout function

Comment: It's for a two-stage and dual level login. Yes, PIN is a second factor but it's part of the access coding to a login area so must be secret.

Comment: Should have mentioned whilst this 'fix' is only for Firefox which doesn't support 
        -moz-text-security:disc; I do want my code to work in all browsers.

Comment: Does the problem continue to exist if you remove the `console.log` line in the `keyup` handler? Logging on the console is blocking and can be sloooow.

Comment: @headache: What’s the threat model where a random code is at risk when entered without masking into a textbox, but not at risk when being read from an e-mail?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is just how the keyup event works, it tends not to be able capture some very fast inputs. Just the way onmousemove works, when the mouse moves very fast, some element will be skipped.

Why not use input type="password" or I think using oninput event can be a work around for you.